# how to create recurring meeting weekly, monthly and yearly in exchange mailbox calendar using EWS Managed API in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to create an Exchange mailbox calendar meeting using EWS Managed API in PowerShell. I am able to create if it is not a recurring meeting but the code is not working for recurrence. I see there are multiple examples of creating recurring meetings in C# but I could not find much help to work recurrence in PowerShell.

When I tried this code. I am getting the error, screenshots are attached.

$recurrence = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence ($Appointment.Start.Date, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DayOfTheWeek]::Wednesday, 1)
$Appointment.Recurrence = $recurrence

[image]

I also tried this code
$Recurrence = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence.WeeklyPattern([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DayOfTheWeek]::Tuesday, 1)
$Appointment.Recurrence = $Recurrence

But got the error
[image]

I am really fed up with this issue because many days have passed and I am still stuck there. EWS Managed API DLL is being loaded and working properly when I create a simple meeting without any recurrence. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrence (and SearchFilters) in the EWS Managed API are nested types see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/nested-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN. But basically you can't create an instance of the enclosing type (as there are no public constructors) eg you can check that in PowerShell using (or just read the source code or documentation for the class)

```
([type]"Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence").GetConstructors()
```

To use nested types in PowerShell you just add a + sign between the enclosing type and nested type eg

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence+WeeklyPattern
```

For the weeklypattern the constructor is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.recurrence.weeklypattern.-ctor?view=exchange-ews-api#microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-recurrence-weeklypattern-ctor(system-datetime-system-int32-microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-dayoftheweek()) so in your example it is missing the StartDate for the recurrence eg it should be

```
$Recurrence = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence+WeeklyPattern((Get-Date),1,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DayOfTheWeek]::Tuesday)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Glen. Just tried Weekly and it worked perfectly. Will the second and third parameters be the same always?

Comment: Depends on the type of occurrence your creating, the documentation may not be correct as it seems to be referring to RelativeYearlyPattern so it maybe they have a cut and paste issue with it.

Comment: So the doco is correct except for the wording but your example was wrong you should be using the interval as the second parameter and day of week as the third it was working because its an enum but you'll be a bad recurrence if you do it that way.

Comment: Actually, I was passing parameters in the wrong order. The correct order is this, and the "interval" parameter specifies the number of weeks. I have set the value of the second parameter to 1, which means the meeting will occur every week.

$Recurrence = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence+WeeklyPattern((Get-Date), 1, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DayOfTheWeek]::Tuesday)

Comment: Just saw your comment after I posted my reply :).You are right. I had identified this issue and corrected it. Thank you very much for your help. it resolved the recurring issue. Otherwise, I had wasted a lot of time on it before.